# Migration from CVS to GIT with cvs2git

Tags: python, git, cvs, cvs2git

I am trying to migrate a CVS repository to GIT. I am using cvs2git. I am running the following command.

```
python cvs2git --blobfile=C:\Users\popai\Downloads\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\git-blob.dat --dumpfile=C:\Users\popai\Downloads\dist\cvs2svn-2.4.0\git-dump.dat --encoding=iso-8859-1 --username=cvs2git C:\Users\popai\Desktop\cvs\datafs\lfs\cvswork\cvsheidi\
```

And I am getting the following error

```
----- pass 4 (FilterSymbolsPass) -----
Filtering out excluded symbols and summarizing items...
ERROR: The command 'cvs -Q -R -f –d :local:C:\\Users\\popai\\Desktop\\cvs\\datafs\\lfs\\cvswork\\cvsheidi co -r1.1 -p -kb CVSROOT/checkoutlist' failed
 with exit status=1
and the following output:
cvs [checkout aborted]: Couldn't open default trigger library: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you try running that command manually in a command prompt?  cvs -Q -R -f –d :local:C:\\Users\\popai\\Desktop\\cvs\\datafs\\lfs\\cvswork\\cvsheidi co -r1.1 -p -kb CVSROOT/checkoutlist

Comment: I get the same when running this command. cvs [checkout aborted]: Couldn't open default trigger library: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Check for the file "default_trigger.dll" in your CVSNT directory. It might be missing due to a bad install. If it is, uninstall, reinstall, and it should be there.

Found at http://www.cvsnt.org/pipermail/cvsnt/2006-January/023158.html

Also you can try to switch to a different CSV from `cygwin`. See https://web3null.blogspot.ru/2013/07/checkout-module-from-local-cvs.html